# cake php session cookie variable not getting created in localhost

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

i have a cake php project that's works like charm on production linux server.

my code from core.php for session handler :

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'cake',
            'cookieTimeout' => 0,
            'cookie' => 'mybeautifulsession'
));
```

when I inspect element i find that there is a cookie with name mybeautifulsession generated for my domain on live.
When same code is executed on localhost, this variable is not being generated as a result my auth component is not working and keeps me redirecting to login page.

How do i get this to work ? What am I missing ? Something pretty stupid for sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Session defaults option 'cake' saves session files in CakePHP's /tmp directory. So make sure /app/tmp directory and all its sub directories in your cake installation is writable by the web server user.

For the site to run, apache needs read and write without execute. For you to access it (assuming you are in the group that owns app/tmp) you also need read and write if you will edit manually things with terminal/finder. All other users should have no rights whatsoever. So:

OSX&Linux: sudo chmod -R 660 app/tmp/. The -R part is to do it recursively for all inside folders. The first 6 is for the user owner (OSX:_www or Linux:www-data), the second 6 is for the group owner (OSX:staff or Linux: johnsmith), the 0 is for all other users/guests.

NOTE: According to this pull request for CakePHP it looks like CakePHP 2.4 will have ability to create subfolders in app/tmp/ which means it will need a 7 instead of 6 for the user now becoming 760.